# Remove an array from computed reverse method Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Good day, how to remove an array from a reverse method?

Here's my code

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            app_title: 'Simple Checklist App',
            entered_task_value: '',
            list_of_tasks: [],
            is_priority: false,
        }
    },
    computed: {
        reverseItems() {
            return [...this.list_of_tasks].reverse();
        }
    },
    methods: {
        add_item() {
            this.list_of_tasks.push(
                {
                    id: this.list_of_tasks.length + 1,
                    data: this.entered_task_value,
                    priority: this.is_priority,
                }
            );
            this.entered_task_value = '';
            this.is_priority = '';
        },
        total_tasks() {
           return this.list_of_tasks.length;
        },
        remove_item(task_index) {
            return this.reverseItems.splice(task_index, 1);
        }
    },
});


app.mount('#app');
```

The `remove_item` method is not working and I am not sure how to properly call the property inside the `computed`

```
remove_item(task_index) {
            return this.reverseItems.splice(task_index, 1);
        }
```

This is the HTML

```
            <ul>
            <li
                v-for="(task, task_index) in reverseItems"
                class="item"
                :key="task.id"
                :class="{priority: task.priority}"
            >
            {{task.id}}
            {{task.data}}
             <button v-on:click="remove_item(task_index)">Remove</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: When adding new item, you are adding into `list_of_tasks` which comes from `data`. This is ok. When removing, you are removing from `reverseItems` which is `computed` - this is not possible. You must remove item from the source array - `list_of_tasks`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update the list_of_tasks of task array instead of the `computed` array.

The computed values are calculated from the real data and updated each time the data changes.

Here is the [documentation about computed properties](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html)  in vue.js

---

Here is a small example

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => {
    return {
      myArr: [1,2,3,4,5]
    }
  },
  
  computed: {
    myArrReversed(){
      return [...this.myArr].reverse()
    }
  },
  
  methods : {
    addItem(){
      this.myArr.push(this.myArr.length +1)
    },
    removeItem(){
      this.myArr.splice(this.myArr.length - 1, 1)
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item of myArrReversed" :key='item'>
      {{item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <button @click="addItem">Add item</button>
  <button @click="removeItem">Remove item</button>

</div>
```